# Are images, flash contents are also treated as hypertext by the HTTP server and the web browser?

Tags: image, http, web, content-type

I am having a doubt about the working of the HTTP protocol.
We know that HTTP is used for transfering the hyperText only. 
Now suppose if I type some url in my browser and press enter the web page is loaded in the browser also the images and the some flash contents(if any) in the in the web page are displayed.

Now my question is that are the images and the flash contents in the web page also treated as hypertext by the HTTP server and the web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GET request is designed to retrieve data from the server. It doesn't really matter what the data is. It's just a resource that can be called by name and is handled by the browser.

Comment: Then why do people use FTP server and HTTP server for different purposes. I mean they can get any data using HTTP server.

Comment: The difference between an FTP server and an HTTP server is another question. It's a bit like asking what the difference is between an IRC chat channel and chatting on MSN. When you set up an FTP you're intending for people to have usernames and passwords that they use to log in, download and upload. If you want you can set up a guest account with the ability to download but not upload. By contrast, an HTTP server is typically supposed to serve content to anybody who knows the URL. Any other functionality is supplied by whatever web application is running on the server.

Comment: And anyway, the nature of HTTP is in the word "hypertext". Hypertext information communicates relationships. The browser automatically retrieves a GIF if the text of the HTML document implies that it should be requested. FTP is not used for this purpose.